# Based on a value entered, bringing the lowest approximate value (previous) or higher (subsequent) in a table

Tags: oracle

I am trying to select the lowest and the highest value or before or after a value in the table.
For example, I'm trying to pick the line that contains the percentage (PERCEN_TOT), greater than the value that I am passing in the search.
Example: if I pass the search value in the "PERCEN_TOT" equal to 23, column should be returned and the following value or earlier (according to research), respectively, would be 3 or 4 of the "LINE" column.
What could researching, was APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT Oracle 12 function, however, I have just installed the Oracle 11.
Can anyone help me please?

**The table is:**

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE
(
  INV_NUMPED   VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  INV_NUMITE   NUMBER,
  INV_CODPRO   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  INV_QTDITE   NUMBER,
  INV_VALITE   NUMBER,
  INV_VALTOT   NUMBER,
  SUM_VTOTAL   NUMBER,
  PERCEN_TOT   NUMBER,
  LINE         NUMBER
);
```

**Table of Contents:**

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '029', '01209434', 48, 40.6, 
    12698.12, 1948.8, 15, 1);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '010', '01211110', 8, 50.85, 
    12698.12, 2355.6, 18, 2);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '026', '01209431', 60, 6.13, 
    12698.12, 2723.4, 21, 3);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '027', '01209432', 60, 6.13, 
    12698.12, 3091.2, 24, 4);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '028', '01209433', 60, 6.13, 
    12698.12, 3459, 27, 5);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '011', '01211109', 4, 91.61, 
    12698.12, 3825.44, 30, 6);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '004', '01211103', 4, 83.3, 
    12698.12, 4158.64, 32, 7);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '033', '01209439', 18, 18.23, 
    12698.12, 4486.78, 35, 8);
INSERT INTO INVOICE
   (INV_NUMPED, INV_NUMITE, INV_CODPRO, INV_QTDITE, INV_VALITE, 
    INV_VALTOT, SUM_VTOTAL, PERCEN_TOT, LINE)
 VALUES
   ('550830', '035', '01209440', 18, 18.23, 
    12698.12, 4814.92, 37, 9);
COMMIT;
```

Thanks in advance!

Double R

Comment: Provide the expected output, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to get you what you're asking for:

```
SELECT *
  FROM INVOICE a
  WHERE a.PERCEN_TOT = (SELECT MAX(PERCEN_TOT)
                        FROM INVOICE
                        WHERE PERCEN_TOT < 23)
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*
  FROM INVOICE a
  WHERE a.PERCEN_TOT = (SELECT MIN(PERCEN_TOT)
                          FROM INVOICE
                          WHERE PERCEN_TOT < 23);
```

Change it around if you need to get back something different.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85a8bd/13)

Share and enjoy.